# awk command does not halt on windows for merging large csv files

Tags: windows, csv, awk

I am executing the following *awk* command on Windows 10.

```
awk "(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)" *.csv > bigMergeFile.csv
```

I want to merge all csv files into a single file named bigMergeFile.csv using only the header of the first file.

I successfully tested the code on small files (4 files each containing 5 cols and 4 rows). However, the code does not halt when I run it on large files (10 files, each with 8k rows, 32k cols, approximate size 1 GB). It only stops execution when the space runs out on hard drive. At that time, the size of resultant output file bigMergeFile.csv is 30GB. The combine files size of all input csv file is 9.5 GB.

I have tested the code on Mac OS and it works fine. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: (not related to the issue you are facing) I'd suggest to use `head -n1 sample.csv ; tail -qn +2 *.csv` instead of `awk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess: bigMergeFile.csv ends in .csv so it's one of the input files your script is running on and it's growing as your script appends to it. It's like you wrote a loop like:

```
while ! end-of-file do
    read line from start of file
    write line to end of file
done
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I changed the extension of output file and it worked. Just out curiosity, why it works on Mac OS and not Windows is beyond comprehension :)

Comment: It's not beyond comprehension, apparently writing to the same file you're reading is just handled differently on different platforms (assuming you really do have your output file included as one of the input files on Mac too). Rule of thumb - never do that!

Answer (score 1):

since you're doing basically a concat not a merge, set FS = "^$" to it won't waste time attempting to split fields you won't need anyway.